# Adding autonumber to HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not new to html per say but I'm definitly not experienced in it and also definitly not in javascript.

I have this table with a textbox and anytime you enter something in the textbox and press the Voeg toe button it gets added to the 2nd column which is correct. However I would like there to be an autonumber in the first column, I've tried multiple thing but cant seem to make it work.

```
     <div id="wrapper">
  <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
    <tr>
      <th>Volgnummer</th>
      <th>Serienummer</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Voeg toe">
          <input type ="button" onclick="scan_barcode();"value="Scan barcode" >
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</div>
```

This is the javascript im using

```
    function add_row()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name").value;


 var table=document.getElementById("data_table");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td></td><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name").value="";

 }
```

I found some css code but all this does is give every row the number 0 instead of 0,1,2 etc etc

```
}

table tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table tr td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
    margin-right: 0.5em;
}
```

Comment: the javascript code does work for auto-incrementing the id, could you explain what you want more thoroughly if that isn't what you meant.

Comment: Why can't you just add a new counter variable into your existing Javascript code and use that to create the autonumber?

Answer (score 1):

Here:

On your css you need to comment or delete the line:

`content: counter(rowNumber);`

and change your javascript:

```
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td>"+table_len+"</td><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td></tr>";
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hrm8k8kh/